# Prepopulating Docusign Template Fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, docusignapi

So I'm trying to prepopulate some fields in our DocuSign Templates when submitting them from our custom interface but the request doesn't seem to be able to find them in the templates. We're using REST, cURL and Codeigniter. My data array is as follows:

```
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId,
    "emailSubject" => "Hello World!",
    "emailBlurb" => "This comes from PHP",
    "templateId" => "********-****-****-****-************",
    "templateRoles" => array(
                           array(
                               "email" => "****@******.com",
                               "name" => "**** *****",
                               "roleName" => "LC3"
                           ),
                           array(
                               "email" => $this->input->post("applicant_email"),
                               "name" => $this->input->post("applicant_name"),
                               "roleName" => "Applicant",
                               "tabStatuses" => array(
                                                    "textTabs" => array (
                                                                      array (
                                                                          "tabLabel" => "lic_num",
                                                                          "tabValue" => $this->input->post("license_number")
                                                                      ),
                                                                      array (
                                                                          "tabLabel" => "ubi_num",
                                                                          "tabValue" => $this->input->post("ubi_number")
                                                                      ),
                                                                      array (
                                                                          "tabLabel" => "tra_nam",
                                                                          "tabValue" => $this->input->post("trade_name")
                                                                      )
                                                                   )
                                                 )
                            )
                      ),
    "status" => "sent");
```

I tried tabs instead of tabStatuses, but that didn't work either and our XML responses have TabStatuses instead of Tabs. Has something changed since the API Walkthroughs were put up?

**EDIT:** So after much trial and error with Chrome's Postman extension, this is the JSON request that I got to actually not error out:

```
{
    "accountId":"c771ba8c-2947-4bec-acab-15b1b48a11b6",
    "emailSubject":"Hello World!",
    "emailBlurb":"This comes from PHP",
    "templateId":"B96D0480-8792-43E8-AE11-E2AEAC74E601",
    "templateRoles":[
        {
            "email":"mike@cloudpwr.com",
            "name":"Mike Longmire",
            "roleName":"LC3",
            "tabStatuses":[
                {
                    "tabStatus":[
                        {
                            "tabLabel":"lic_num",
                            "tabValue":"1111"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel":"ubi_num",
                            "tabValue":"2222"
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel":"tra_nam",
                            "tabValue":"Flakey"
                        }
                     ]
                 }
             ],
             "email":"duckie715@gmail.com",
             "name":"Mike Longmire",
             "roleName":"Applicant"
        }
     ],
    "status":"sent"
}
```

I get back my same response:

```
{
    "envelopeId": "0063d398-36b7-4e2f-8515-6ed9ab62aaeb",
    "uri": "/envelopes/0063d398-36b7-4e2f-8515-6ed9ab62aaeb",
    "statusDateTime": "2013-10-08T18:05:54.9926661Z",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The first step in troubleshooting a DocuSign API request (or any API request, for that matter) that isn't behaving as you'd expect should be to examine the full JSON (or XML) request that you're sending to the server. (Using Fiddler or a similar tool, this is easy to do.) Seeing the raw request contents and comparing it with DocuSign code samples and documentation should allow you to identify the problem with the request structure/contents -- then you can adjust your code accordingly. If you can post your Request XML or JSON here, I'd gladly provide feedback on potential causes of your issue.

Comment: I would love to, but I can't get Fiddler to work on my Mac. Can you recommend another application? I have a quasi json print out from the data_string variable.

Comment: So now when I click my "Create Envelope" menu link, it gives me the "error calling webservice, status is:400" error. I'm wondering if it doesn't like the Codeigniter syntax, i.e. $this->input->post(), even though it does work.

Comment: So it's actually the email address. Is there a special way to handle email addresses in Header Requests?

Comment: It still doesn't write to the fields in the templates.

Comment: Just a heads-up that you're going to need to figure out how to generate a full trace of the Request and Response sooner or later -- being able to do so is a requirement of the DocuSign API Certification process.  Until you're able to do so, you won't be able to pass certification and deploy your integration to Production. So, you might as well figure that out sooner rather than later, as it'll help you troubleshoot issues like this during development as well. :)  I'm not a Mac person, but you might start with a simple Google search for "mac fiddler".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the values being returned from your function calls inside the JSON not being wrapped by quotation **(")** marks.  To test that theory I would first just hardcode some values wherever you have a function call in your JSON (such as `"email" => $this->input->post("applicant_email")`) and replace with actual emails, etc and run.

If you still get the 400 error then something else is wrong with your request.  If you don't, then you just need to prepend and append quotes around the values that are passed back by those function calls.

For instance, you can assign to variables, such as

```
$applicantEmail_1 = $this->input->post("applicant_email")
```

then setup your JSON like:

```
"templateRoles" => array(
                       array(
                           "email" => "****@******.com",
                           "name" => "**** *****",
                           "roleName" => "LC3"
                       ),
                       array(
                           "email" => "$applicantEmail_1",
                           "name" => $this->input->post("applicant_name"),
                           "roleName" => "Applicant",
                       ...
```

The nice thing about PHP is that even though that variable is in double quotes the value of the variable will still be inserted inside the quotes.

Comment: That fixed it for the email issue, but I still can't get it to write to the fields.

Comment: By that do you mean you're not getting an error anymore, but it's not pre-populating your envelope tabs?  If that's the case make sure you are using `tab` not `tabStatuses` in your JSON and confirm that you the tabLabel you are passing in code exactly matches the tab label you added the tab with through the Console.

Comment: Yes. I just changed it to tab, but it still isn't prepopulating.

Comment: I was using TabStatuses and TabStatus because in our response XML, there is no Tabs and Tab.

Comment: So looking at the Template I just downloaded, it is indeed Tabs (my mistake). Should the next step in be Tab and not TextTabs?

Comment: I did a webinar back in april which had three examples, take a look at example2.json to see what the JSON should look like.  [Here is the link to the webinar files on GitHub](https://github.com/Ergin008/DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013?source=cc)  The quick answer, is that it goes templateRoles -> tabs -> textTabs

Comment: I have looked at those webinars, hence where I started with this. I actually found the problem. I moved the Tabs array above the recipient arrays and got the Trade Name field to populate, but the other two did not. I decided to play a hunch and change the other two fields from Number to Text and they ended up filling in. I guess I will have to let our form designer know that he has to change those fields on all our templates, unless you know a way to cast that string as a number?

Comment: We don't have to worry about casting to a number. Thanks for all your help everyone.